# AEM 6.2 Startup errors ESAPI directory or file not readable

Tags: aem

When i started AEM instance, in console i seen **validation.properties FileNotFound Error**,

Complete Log :

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
31.05.2016 17:24:26.379 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=crx-quickstart (command line)
31.05.2016 17:24:26.395 *INFO * [main] Starting Apache Sling in D:\AEM 6.2\crx-quickstart
31.05.2016 17:24:26.395 *INFO * [main] Sling  Extension Lib Home : D:\AEM 6.2\crx-quickstart\launchpad\ext
31.05.2016 17:24:26.395 *INFO * [Apache Sling Control Listener@/127.0.0.1:56056] Apache Sling Control Listener started
31.05.2016 17:24:26.410 *INFO * [main] Checking launcher JAR in folder D:\AEM 6.2\crx-quickstart\launchpad
31.05.2016 17:24:26.426 *INFO * [main] Existing launcher is up to date, using it: 5.4.0.2_6_10-B004 (org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar)
31.05.2016 17:24:26.441 *INFO * [main] Loading launcher class org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.app.MainDelegate from org.apache.sling.launchpad.base.jar
31.05.2016 17:24:26.444 *INFO * [main] External Libs Home (ext) is null or does not exists.
31.05.2016 17:24:26.459 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.properties=conf/sling.properties
31.05.2016 17:24:26.461 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=crx-quickstart
31.05.2016 17:24:26.463 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.launchpad=D:\AEM 6.2\crx-quickstart\launchpad
31.05.2016 17:24:26.464 *INFO * [main] Setting org.osgi.service.http.port=4502
31.05.2016 17:24:26.465 *INFO * [main] Starting launcher ...
31.05.2016 17:24:26.476 *INFO * [main] HTTP server port: 4502
31.05.2016 17:24:27.706 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.commons.log.logback.internal.Activator LogbackManager initialized at bundle startup
31.05.2016 17:24:27.726 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.commons.logservice Service [org.apache.sling.commons.logservice.internal.LogServiceFactory,18, [org.osgi.service.log.LogService]] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
31.05.2016 17:24:27.731 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.commons.logservice Service [org.apache.sling.commons.logservice.internal.LogReaderServiceFactory,19, [org.osgi.service.log.LogReaderService]] ServiceEvent REGISTERED
31.05.2016 17:24:27.736 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.commons.logservice BundleEvent STARTED
31.05.2016 17:24:27.740 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.installer.core BundleEvent RESOLVED
31.05.2016 17:24:27.740 *INFO* [FelixStartLevel] org.apache.sling.installer.core BundleEvent STARTING
**Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: D:\AEM 6.2\ESAPI.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties
Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\Raj Kumar) directory: C:\Users\Raj Kumar\esapi\ESAPI.properties
Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using class loader for DefaultSecurityConfiguration class!
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: D:\AEM 6.2\validation.properties
Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\validation.properties
Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\Raj Kumar) directory: C:\Users\Raj Kumar\esapi\validation.properties
Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.**
SUCCESSFULLY LOADED validation.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using class loader for DefaultSecurityConfiguration class!
RAWProcessor succesfully installed
31.05.2016 17:24:52.803 *INFO * [main] Startup completed
```

Error :

```
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
    Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
    Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: D:\AEM 6.2\ESAPI.properties
    Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\ESAPI.properties
    Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\Raj Kumar) directory: C:\Users\Raj Kumar\esapi\ESAPI.properties
    Loading ESAPI.properties via file I/O failed. Exception was: java.io.FileNotFoundException
    Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via the classpath.
    SUCCESSFULLY LOADED ESAPI.properties via the CLASSPATH from '/ (root)' using class loader for DefaultSecurityConfiguration class!
    Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
    Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
    Not found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory or file not readable: D:\AEM 6.2\validation.properties
    Not found in SystemResource Directory/resourceDirectory: .esapi\validation.properties
    Not found in 'user.home' (C:\Users\Raj Kumar) directory: C:\Users\Raj Kumar\esapi\validation.properties
    Loading validation.properties via file I/O failed.
    Attempting to load validation.properties via the classpath.
```

what is validation.properties file ?

how to fix this error ?

i seen the same error for CQ 5.6 too, but didn't get the idea of root cause of it.
can anyone explain ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

The validation.properties file is used inside the **"com.day.cq.cq-xssprotection"**. bundle
 To see what it contains

1. Go to Felix console (http://host:port/system/console/bundles/) find out the bundle number named  "Adobe Granite XSS Protection (com.day.cq.cq-xssprotection)".
2. Go to your-aem-instalation-folder\crx-quickstart\launchpad\felix and find the folder named with same bundle number.
3. copy the bundle inside the bundle folder with some default version0.0 to some path.
4. Use any decompiler and see there will be ESAPI.properties which will contain validation.properties entry and at same level you will have a validation.properties file also included in the same bundle.
   [image]

While startup of AEM instance you can see the below error in the **stdout.log** file. which tells you from where it is being successfully loaded.

[image]

You can find more details about it at below.
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Enterprise_Security_API

And to customize the vaidator properties file you can try
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ESAPI_Getting_Started_Guide